# PostgreSQL real type vs double type query result confusion

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE number_data_types 
(
    numeric_column NUMERIC(20,5),
    real_column REAL,
    double_column DOUBLE PRECISION
);
```

Inserting the following sample data:

```
INSERT INTO number_data_types
VALUES
    (2.13579, 2.13579, 2.13579),
    (2.1357987654, 2.1357987654, 2.1357987654);

SELECT * FROM number_data_types;
```

The result:

```
2.13579;2.13579;2.13579
2.13580;2.1358;2.1357987654
```

How come the second row query result is **"2.1358"** for the `REAL` type?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the question.  You have two values:

```
2.13579
2.1357987654
```

When Postgres is putting the real value, it is removing the trailing zeros.  There are at least six significant digits, so these are interpreted as pretty close to:

```
2.13579
2.13580
```

However, the `0` is suppressed in the result set.  You can readily see this if you insert `2.13580` into the real column.